# Multiple selects on one query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to do a multiple select in mysql but have not had any joy. I have tried following examples on here and around the web but they do not seam to fit what I am trying to do.

My select statement is as follows

```
SELECT a.* FROM Calendar a 
WHERE a.CalendarId = 256 AND a.Private = 0
UNION
SELECT b.* FROM Calendar b
WHERE b.CalendarId = 256 AND b.Private = 1 AND b.PrivateId = 11
```

To explain what I want above, I would like to return all Calendar rows that have a Private value of 0.

I would also like to filter this by selecting only those that have `Private = 1` that have the `PrivateId = 11` (in this example).

Thanks

Comment: I think you want an `INTERSECTION` not a `UNION`...

Comment: what's the difference between what you expected and the real example you tired

Comment: @Hitman47 I was trying to use JOIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT *
FROM Calendar
WHERE CalendarId = 256
    AND (Private = 0 OR (Private = 1 AND PrivateId = 11))
```

Comment: new format made it even worse :) I'd keep it 2-liner but move CalendarId into first line

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I guess I was trying to overcomplicate it.